# Creating a ListView Control in Default Edit Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a ListView Control in Asp.net 4.0 C#
I am attempting to make the default mode = Edit Mode with text boxes. So I took the Item Template (the default template) and replaced my databound labels with TextBoxes.
It works ok. Except the text Boxes only apply to every other row. So half the rows are text boxes on Page Load and half the Roes are still Labels. Here is my code:

```
       <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="">
            <td>
          <asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>

                     <asp:TextBox ID="DiscountPercentageTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("DiscountPercentage") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>

            <asp:TextBox ID="CashTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Cash") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
       <LayoutTemplate>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title </th>
                <th>DiscountPercentage</th>
                <th>Cash</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
        </tbody>
    </table>
</LayoutTemplate>
```

And here is the result:

[image]

You see? Every other row is a textbox. I need all rows to be textboxes. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh, do you have an AlternatingItemTemplate defined?  The ListVIew has no intelligence to make the original fields as labels....

Try making the ALternatingItemTemplate as the ItemTemplate too, if you don't have one defined.

Comment: Yes!! Thank you That did it! Green Check Mark!